# ssh: connect to host [public ip] port 22: Connection refused

Tags: ssh, centos7

I have a CentOS 7 VM Instance on GCP, I have a cron job on my local infra that connects to GCP Instance every minute to check some parameters on GCP VM Instance.

Most of the time the ssh [public ip] command works, but some times I get this error  "ssh: connect to host [public ip]  port 22: Connection refused"

Is there max connection limit that I can increase.

Thanks

IJ

Answer (score 0):

Indeed. Check sshd_config's man page `man sshd_config`

If not already, it might not be a bad idea to check your auth.log for some additional info as well.

```
[root@server ~]# vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
# make the changes and restart the service
[root@server ~]# systemctl restart sshd
```

Some more info on the configuration variables:

> **MaxSessions**
>           Specifies the maximum number of open shell, login or subsystem
>           (e.g. sftp) sessions permitted per network connection.  Multiple
>           sessions may be established by clients that support connection
>           multiplexing.  Setting MaxSessions to 1 will effectively disable
>           session multiplexing, whereas setting it to 0 will prevent all
>           shell, login and subsystem sessions while still permitting for-
>           warding.  The default is 10.
>
> **MaxStartups**
>           Specifies the maximum number of concurrent unauthenticated con-
>           nections to the SSH daemon.  Additional connections will be
>           dropped until authentication succeeds or the LoginGraceTime
>           expires for a connection.  The default is 10:30:100.
>           Alternatively, random early drop can be enabled by specifying the
>           three colon separated values start:rate:full (e.g. "10:30:60").
>           sshd(8) will refuse connection attempts with a probability of
>           rate/100 (30%) if there are currently start (10) unauthenticated
>           connections.  The probability increases linearly and all connec-
>           tion attempts are refused if the number of unauthenticated con-
>           nections reaches full (60).